# Laravel Nova Multiselect (on create Error Array to string)

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I try using multiselect when creating record but I get error Array to String.
But when I update record everything is ok.

```
            Panel::make('Material', [
            MultiSelect::make('Select materials', 'material_id')
                ->options(Material::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                ->hideFromIndex(),
        ]),
```

I need hide this filed when creating record to use him on update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What database type is `material_id`? Make sure it's a database field that allows to save array's.

One other thing that could cause this if you didn't cast the field in your model to array

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'material_id' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) A forget about cast in model.